# How do you use xmlhttprequest in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest

I am currently trying to run an app on ionic, and found an issue when using xmlhttprequest in our code. I am trying to parse a text file and implement it in our code, but every time I run it the page just won't open.

Comment: you should show some code and/or error(s)

Comment: what version of ionic ?

Comment: It is ionic 2. Also, I resolved my issue by just running it with live preview instead. I am, however, having issues adding a new page for the ionic side menu template.

Comment: Also, here is the link to my code:https://github.com/eva316/eva316.github.io

Comment: @Ladmerc I have the code